# How do I convert string version of an array into an actual array?

Tags: python

```
s = "[[A, B],[E,R], [E,G]]"
```

Is there a built-in way to convert this string into an array? (s[][])

Comment: By "array", do you mean Python list?  Are the values supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but in your case it will assume `A B E R G` to be variables, is this the case?
If this is not the case you will need to do some extra formatting with the string.

This will work if the variables `A B E R G` are set:
`s = eval(s)`

If the letters need to be strings you will have to do some kind of regexp to replace all occurrences of chars with quoted chars.

Comment: If the letters were meant to be strings, there is no reason not to use the much safer [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval`, which may execute arbitrary code if s has been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

If A B E R G are not variables but just a string then you can use the following code:

```
tmp = ''
for c in s:
   if c.isalpha():
      t+="'%s'"%c
   else:
      t+=c
eval(t) # will give you [['A', 'B'], ['E', 'R'], ['E', 'G']]
```

OR:(very ugly i know but don't beat me too much - just experementing)

```
evel(''.join(map(lambda x: s[x[0]] if not s[x[0]].isalpha() else "'%s'" % s[x[0]], enumerate(map(lambda c: c.isalpha(), s)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can slightly modify the string, you could use the JSON module to convert the string into list.

```
>>> import json

>>> s = '[["A", "B"], ["E", "R"], ["E", "G"]]'
>>> array = json.loads(s)
>>> array
[[u'A', u'B'], [u'E', u'R'], [u'E', u'G']]
```